# Finite temperature greens function in grand canonical ensemble

Tags: hamiltonian, second-quantization, time-evolution

I see this question was asked several times before but I don't think any answer can explain the issue perfectly. I am studying many body theory and encounters finite temperature Green's function. At first glance, it seems to me that the correct time dependence of, let's say a greater green's function, would be

$$
\begin{align*}
G^{>}\left(\vec{r},\sigma,t;\vec{r}',\sigma',t'\right)&=-i\left\langle c_{\vec{r},\sigma}(t),c_{\vec{r}',\sigma'}^{\dagger}(t')\right\rangle \\
&=-\frac{i}{Z}\mathrm{tr}\left[e^{-\beta\left(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N}\right)}e^{i\hat{H}t}c_{\vec{r},\sigma}e^{-i\hat{H}t}e^{i\hat{H}t'}c_{\vec{r}',\sigma'}^{\dagger}e^{-i\hat{H}t'}\right]
\end{align*}
$$

However, some texts used the "grand canonical Hamiltonian" $H_{G}=H-\mu N$ for the operators. Some said it is a natural way to "define" the time evolution, some don't even say anything at the beginning and include $\mu$ in all the Hamiltonian, some say it is merely a parameter but not chemical potential.

Of course if $\left[\hat{H},\hat{N}\right]=0$, such a change in Hamiltonian just introduces an extra phase factor like $e^{i\mu\left(t-t'\right)}$ to the Green's function and the change can be reversed at the final result easily. BUT if $\left[\hat{H},\hat{N}\right]\neq 0$ like a BCS hamiltonian, diagonalizing $\hat{H}$ and diagonalizing $\hat{H}_{G}$ give two completely different set of "eigen-operators" like
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{H}&=\sum_{i\sigma}E_{i\sigma}\hat{\gamma}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}\hat{\gamma}_{i\sigma}\\
\hat{H}_{G}&=\sum_{i\sigma}\tilde{E}_{i\sigma}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{i\sigma}
\end{align*}
$$
In this case, changing $H$ to $H_G$ in the green's function will not just produce a phase factor but instead you are really calculating something very different.

Is there some theoretical reason that requires the time evolution is generated by $H_G$ instead of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I remember, that I wasn't satisfied, when I saw the motivation of introducing this Hamiltonian in Landau&Lifshitz. Maybe the possible way to proceed is to start, from the grand-canocical ensemble, for which formula can be derived on the grounds of *MaxEntropy* method (maximisation of entropy subject to the conditions of conserved charges having fixed values).
$$
Z = \text{Tr} e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)}
$$
Where $\beta$ is Lagrange multiplier for conserved energy $E$, and $-\beta \mu$ for the number of particles. Having fixed these factors, one then proceeds with analogy to the evolution operator in Euclidean time:
$$
e^{-\tau \hat{H}}
$$